# AngularJS adding text inside a <div>

Tags: html, angularjs

In jQuery I can do something like the following to add desired text inside a div or any element.

```
$( "#div1" ).html( "<span class='red'>Hello <b>Again</b></span>" );
```

How can I do similar operation using AngularJS.

I need to add a plain text inside a div when the user clicks on a link.

Here's what I have tried:

**View:**

```
<a ng-click="showProductText($index)">Click Me</a>
```

**ng-controller:**

```
$scope.showProductText = function () {
   var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#customerProductCatalogText'));
   --need help hence forth--
    };
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 6):

In view

```
<div style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;" ng-bind-html="divText"></div>
```

and in Controller

```
$scope.divText = '<H2>some text</H2>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in different way "more angular then jQuery" using directive "ng-if" please see here 
http://jsbin.com/tuvom/1/edit

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in products">
      <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
      <button ng-if="!item.showdescription" ng-click="item.showdescription= !item.showdescription">Show description</button>
      <button ng-if="item.showdescription" ng-click="item.showdescription= !item.showdescription">Hide description</button>
      <p ng-if="item.showdescription">{{item.description}}</p>
    </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.products = [

    {name:"item one", description:"so the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."},
    {name:"item two", description:"so the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."},

  ];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This link helped me solve the problem [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

This did the trick:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#customerProductCatalogText')).html("NewText");
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with accepting your own answer if it indeed is the solution you were looking for.  Though, it seems @shridhar-sagari shows the more angular preferred way

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
angular.element('#customerProductCatalogText').innerHTML="<span class='red'>Hello <b>Again</b></span>";
```